# Is there any way we can disable the access of microphone/webcam? on browser

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

If i am accessing a microphone using `getUserMedia()` is it possible to remove/disable the access after the record has finished (stopped)? i am not talking about `MediaStreamRecorder.Stop()`

i have a requirement of recording audio from user multiple times in a single page(using the multiview property)

i have tried to use the same javascript to access the microphone but on the second situation its showing the error

> 1.InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable at function below
>
> `startRecordingnew()`

Below i have given the JS i have used:

```
var recordButton, stopButton, recorder;


window.onload = function () {

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true
    })
    .then(function (stream) {
        if (recorder == null) {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            alert(stream)
            recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', onRecordingReady);
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        alert(err)
    });;
};


function startRecordingnew() {

    recorder.start();

}

function stopRecordingnew() {

    recorder.stop();
}
```

For the first scenario its a success! Can anybody tell me how can i achieve this? i was thinking about disabling the access of microphone when the first scenario recording is finished. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why not simply pause recording using recorder.pause() ?

Comment: when iam stopping the record its showing the error since my requirement is to save the recorded audio.How a pause function would help here?